# SQL Contains or LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to run a query on a column which looks for "word 1" or "word 2" AND if either of those exist the result needs to contain "Word 3"

The column itself can be huge with massive amounts of text in it, this is what I have so far and it doesn't return what i'm looking:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE column LIKE "%word.1%" OR 
      column LIKE "%word.2%" AND 
      column LIKE "%word3%";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i was temped to voteclose this as a simple typographical error as [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) is involved as @scaisEdge suggested in his answer.. Only problem as the data is huge `LIKE "%word.1%"` will not scale as it never can use a index so for this query the complete table file will be scanned.. But instead of voteclosing it i provided a way of optimizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shoudl use () to manage the two OR coindition  together

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ( column LIKE "%word.1%" OR column LIKE "%word.2%" ) 
  AND column LIKE "%word3%" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The column itself can be huge with massive amounts of text in it

in that case i would suggest [FULL TEXT indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) as`LIKE '%search%'` will not scale as it never can be optimized by using indexes.

And use  `MATCH() ... AGAINST` to match something like

```
SELECT 
 ...
WHERE
MATCH (column )
    AGAINST ('word.1 word.2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

> MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in
>   which
>
> ```
> + stands for AND
>
> - stands for NOT
>
> [no operator] implies OR
> ```
>
> [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Which should be the same as writting. (scaisEdge 's answer)

```
 SELECT 
 ...
 WHERE
    ( column LIKE "%word.1%" OR column LIKE "%word.2%" ) 
  AND
    column LIKE "%word3%"
```